# Cordova: Share webview cookies with native plugins

Tags: android, ios, cordova, authentication, cookies

I have a cordova app, running iOS and Android, which uses cookies for authentication (the user just types in email and password, and the in app browser sets the cookies, backend in Rails with devise). This works so far.

Now I have a native plugin for android and iOS, which uploads some data in background mode (iOS) / as a service (Android). The problem is, that the URL the plugin is trying to access is also protected. So the plugins somehow needs to send the cookies along with the request.

I have found a number of articles, most of them a little bit old (like this one http://blog.winfieldpeterson.com/2013/01/17/cookies-in-hybrid-android-apps), and every solutoin feels like a little bit of overkill.

I'm using Cordova 4.3.0, and maybe there is a standard solution to this, that I haven't found (and got updated since all the other articles were written).

Here is a part of my Android and iOS code, which sends the data to the server:

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(httpclient.getParams(), registry);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, httpclient.getParams());

// Set verifier
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(locationCache.getUrl());
httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

JSONObject body;
body = new JSONObject();
body.put("someKey", "someData");

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

And the iOS version:

```
NSError * err;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:geodata options:0 error:&err];
NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]];
postRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[postRequest setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
postRequest.HTTPBody = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:postRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if(error) {
                             NSLog(@"Httperror: %@, %d", error.localizedDescription, error.code);
                           } else {
                              NSInteger responseCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
                              NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                              NSLog(@"REQUEST SENT TO SERVER! HTTP response code: %d; response body: %@", responseCode, responseString);
                           }
                       }];
```

Hope somedbody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS you can get the cookies for an url like this:

```
NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"__YOUR_URL__"]];
```

or all the cookies like this:

```
NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
```

after that, you can set the request header like this:

```
NSDictionary *headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];
[postRequest setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
```

On android you have the webview [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html)

```
CookieManager cookieManager=CookieManager.getInstance();
String cookie=cookieManager.getCookie(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it with android (iOS follows tomorrow), but the `cookie` variable is `null`. I had a look at `cookieManager.acceptCookie()` which is `true`, and `cookieManager.hasCookies()` is `false`. Do I have to specify which webview to use? I assume that there is only one webview for the whole Cordova app, right?

Comment: There are two android cookieManager, did you import the java.webkit or the java.net? It should be the first one, but try both

Comment: I'm using `import android.webkit.CookieManager;`. When I try to import `import java.webkit.CookieManager;`, the package doesn't exist. When using `import java.net.CookieManager;` it throws an runtime error `cannot find symbol method getInstance()`. But non of them is working... Any other ideas?

Comment: the cookies you are using have expiration date? I've seen that the inAppBrowser plugin deletes cookies without expiration date when you launch it